# Count number of Excel columns with value (do not count blank columns)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count

I have 3 rows x 13 columns with the following data:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

1 2 3 4

1 5 6 7 8
```

Usually, I use `MAX(COUNT(A4:L4),COUNT(A5:L5),COUNT(A6:L6))`.

I have close to 40 excel files with varying areas. So, to do each row range , is very tedious and time consuming. Imagine, for 1 file, I have to select 10 times for 10 rows. Alternatively, selecting the area is only 1 time activity.  Is there another way to do this with a single line of code?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

[image]

Formula in `A1`:

```
=MAX(MMULT(--ISNUMBER(A4:L6),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A4:L6),,,0)))
```

Or, pre-Microsoft365:

```
=MAX(MMULT(--ISNUMBER(A4:L6),ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,COLUMNS(A4:L6)))^0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of nom empty cells in a row with COUNTA:

[image]

My formula in F1 is:

`=COUNTA(A1:E1)`

And drag down. Same formula to count number of columns in each row :)

You need to do this once **Per file** (but not for each row)